# Group rows based on condition on multiple Column values in pandas

Tags: pandas, merge, conditional-statements, rows

I have a Dataframe like follows:

```
text            x0          x1
abc             30.000      81.140
def             94.000      118.450
xyz             121.230     141.230
1234            144.010     155.670
5678            161.230     204.570
dgdfg           207.350     222.910
dfgdf           277.000     304.780
fdfgdfgdfgdf    400.310     462.000
dfgdfgdftt      503.310     565.000
915417953130    94.000      160.720
915417218199    277.000     343.720
```

I want to group the `text` based on the closeness between `x1` to `x0`, as if the current row `x0` is close enough to previous row `x1` of about 10 than the `text` should be merge. 
eg. Here `'def'` and `'xyz'` should be merge as `121.23(x0)` is close to previous row `118.450(x1)`. I want to implement in `pandas`.

Comment: what did you try so far? I'd suggest to take a look at [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html),  maybe [abs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html) and [lt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with tolerance parameter:

```
df1 = df[['text','x0']].sort_values('x0')
df2 = df[['text','x1']].sort_values('x1')

df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on='x0', right_on='x1', tolerance=10)
df['new'] = df['text_x'] + ' ' + df['text_y']
print (df)
          text_x      x0        text_y      x1                new
0            abc   30.00           NaN     NaN                NaN
1            def   94.00           NaN     NaN                NaN
2   915417953130   94.00           NaN     NaN                NaN
3            xyz  121.23           def  118.45            xyz def
4           1234  144.01           xyz  141.23           1234 xyz
5           5678  161.23  915417953130  160.72  5678 915417953130
6          dgdfg  207.35          5678  204.57         dgdfg 5678
7          dfgdf  277.00           NaN     NaN                NaN
8   915417218199  277.00           NaN     NaN                NaN
9   fdfgdfgdfgdf  400.31           NaN     NaN                NaN
10    dfgdfgdftt  503.31           NaN     NaN                NaN
```

Comment: It is giving me `MergeError: key must be integer or timestamp`. Shall I have to convert it to `int`?

Comment: @abhi1610 - yop, or if possible upgrade pandas, I think in new version no error